# Remote Attribute doesn't work anymore

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, repository

I have Project that I used Repository and Interface. I want to control Duplicate `UserName` by Remote attribute. I used method in `_UserRepository` that check Duplicate `UserName`.

**My UserModel**

```
public partial class Users
{
    public Users()
    { this.NEWSs = new HashSet<NEWS>(); }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Family { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Remote("UserNameExists", "Users", "Username is already taken.")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    public string PassWord { get; set; }
```

**_UserRepository**

```
public   Models.Users GetUserByName(string  User)
{
    var src = from b in DbContext.Userss where b.UserName == User select b.UserName;
    return DbContext.Userss.Find(src);
}
```

and **UserNameExists Code in UsersController**

```
public virtual JsonResult UserNameExists(string UserName)
{
    Users user = userRepository.GetUserByName(UserName);
    return user == null ?
        Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet) :
        Json(string.Format("{0} is not available.", UserName),
            JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I run Inspector and open console when running project.I see below error.

http://localhost:57553/Users/UserNameExists?area=Username%20is%20already%20taken.&UserName=mz1368 500 (Internal Server Error)

However, I think code is right and the problem of JSON or jQuery Reference.

Comment: What exactly goes wrong? Are you getting exceptions or unexpected result? Have you debugged it? Does action and repository method gets called? Please, be more specific.

Comment: `UserController` or `UsersController`? (the `RemoteAttribute` specifies it as `UsersController`

Comment: Note you can simplify your `UserNameExists()` method to `return Json(user != null, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` - you have already specified the message in the attribute

Comment: UsersController @StephenMuecke.that's right.

Comment: @StephenMuecke,I edit it ,please see again.

Comment: `500 Internal Server Error` means your controller code is throwing an exception. But your `GetUserByName(string  User)` does not make sense. Why do you have 2 lines of code calling the database to get the same object (and I suspect if `src == null;` then the 2nd line throws an error). Just use one line of code - `return DbContext.Userss.Where(u.UserName == User).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: what is u in u.UserName == User? @StephenMuecke excuseme

Comment: Sorry, that should be `.Where(u => u.UserName == User).FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: Models.Users u; is that right ? @StephenMuecke

Comment: ok ,Thanks @StephenMuecke

Comment: @StephenMuecke Solved.Thankssss.

Answer (score 0):

Change your attribute to this:

```
[Remote("UserNameExists", "Users", HttpMethod = "POST", ErrorMessage = "Username is already taken.")]
```

Also as @Stephen mentioned you can simplify your action method, Something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UserNameExists(string UserName)
{
    if (userRepository.IsUserExist(UserName)) return Json(false);
    return Json(true);
}
```

And:

```
public bool IsUserExist(string user)
{
    return DbContext.Users.Any(x => x.User == user);
}
```

Comment: Hezhbari Sirwan .Thanks ,Solved.